# FOSRestBundle force one route in format html

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3, fosrestbundle

It is possible to make sure that only a single route is made available only in html format?

In the configuration I set html and json, but for only one route I would like the json was not used.

Can you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried this as I am on a cell phone but have you looked at trying something like this just for that one route:

```
my-awesome-route:
  pattern:  /hello/{fist_name}/{last_name}.{_format}
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeHelloBundle:Default:index, _format:html}
requirements:
  _format: html
```

Comment: Thank you!
This is a great system, but in this way exclude the system of routes FOSRestBundle and you have to declare any route manually!
It would be nice that you could do without excluding the routing system, the bundle!

Answer (score 2):

You can call `setFormat('html')` on the view in your controller action.

For example to only render and return a template:

```
class AcmeController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function getAction()
    {
        // ...
        $templateData = [
            'some'  => $vars,
        ];

        $view = $this->view(null, 200)
            ->setFormat('html')
            ->setTemplate("AcmeBundle:Tpl:some.html.twig")
            ->setTemplateData($templateData);

        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
}
```

But then the view handler will always try to render a template. If you don't need to render because you already have your html, just return a new symfony response with the correct headers:

```
class AcmeController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function getAction()
    {
        // you already have $html

        $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'];

        return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::create($html, 200, $headers);
    }
}
```